# Stored Procedure How to Insert Multiple rows into DB from a list of lists

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MySql DB table as follows:

### id | page_name | language | item_id | item_text

The table holds language-based text for use on various pages in a web app. I have the translated text for multiple languages and multiple pages in JSON files in the following format:

```
[
    ["home","fr",1,"French text item 1"]
    ["home","fr",2,"French text item 2"]
    ["home","fr",3,"French text item 3"]
    ["home","fr",4,"French text item 4"]
    ["home","fr",5,"French text item 5"]
]
```

Each JSON document includes the data for one particular language and one particular web page.

I have a large amount of data to insert and I am trying to find a way to efficiently add this data into my DB. I'm assuming a stored procedure that would be the best way but I am struggling to find any tutorials that cover looping though arrays like this and inserting.

Is it possible to feed an array like this into a stored proc and loop through it, inserting each row?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [JSON_TABLE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                   page_name VARCHAR(64),
                   language CHAR(2),
                   item_id INT,
                   item_text VARCHAR(255)
                   );
```

```
SET @data := '
[
    ["home","fr",1,"French text item 1"],
    ["home","fr",2,"French text item 2"],
    ["home","fr",3,"French text item 3"],
    ["home","fr",4,"French text item 4"],
    ["home","fr",5,"French text item 5"]
]
  ';
```

```
INSERT INTO test (page_name, language, item_id, item_text)
SELECT page_name, language, item_id, item_text
FROM JSON_TABLE(@data,
                '$[*]' COLUMNS ( page_name VARCHAR(64) PATH '$[0]',
                                 language CHAR(2) PATH '$[1]',
                                 item_id INT PATH '$[2]',
                                 item_text VARCHAR(255) PATH '$[3]'                                    
                                )
                ) jsontable;
```

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | page_name | language | item_id | item_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | home | fr | 1 | French text item 1 |
| 2 | home | fr | 2 | French text item 2 |
| 3 | home | fr | 3 | French text item 3 |
| 4 | home | fr | 4 | French text item 4 |
| 5 | home | fr | 5 | French text item 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J95j-aRL)